# Are modes in jazz primarily a melody thing?

Tags: theory, jazz, modes, improvisation, melody

I was wondering when jazz cats talk about how they'd use a Lydian scale to improvise over a major chord, or a Dorian scale to improvise over a minor chord they're mainly talking about the melody? So the harmony is generally diatonic chords of the scale (say ii7-V7-I7). So in the key of C major that'd be Dm7, G7, Cmaj7. The improvisation (as an example) would be D Dorian, G Mixolydian, C Lydian. So in a piano, that'd just be my right hand doing that modal stuff (and keep away from b9 avoid notes with whatever chord tone I’m currently on) and my left hand remains in C major.

Does that sound right? I think the improvised melodies are modal and sometimes altered modal scales. But we're just talking about the *melody* right? They keep the harmony pretty basic/diatonic chords?

Edit: the word 'modal' was used wrong here. I just meant modes.

Comment: To play in a mode is more than just playing the right notes. You need to make the root of the mode feel like home and that is the difference between playing in C major or D Dorian. Same notes but D sounds like home in one and C in the other

Comment: I think of the Dorian mode as a sorta *"Chanty"* variant of a minor (or Aeolian) key.  All the same except for that 6th.

Comment: just because of the major or minor third, i like to think of Ionian, Mixolydian, and Lydian as "major" modes, Dorian, Phrygian, and Aeolian as "minor" modes, and Locrian as a diminished key.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson - that's exactly how the modes are perceived. The 3rds are defining. Can't have a *diminished key* though!

Comment: @b3ko exactly, I guess my question is does the harmony/left-hand change that root or does it keep it in the original scale. I've been looking at jazz standards and they all seem diatonic (except for secondary dominants) as far as whatever scale is currently being played harmony wise. the melody however, really changes things up when improvisation is concerned.

Comment: so @Tim , what do you call the Locrian mode?  B-to-B on the white keys.  diminished 5th.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson - funnily enough, I call it the 'Locrian mode'.  Rarely use it - same as most players, but it certainly is not a key. That's pretty well an accepted fact.

Comment: yes @Tim , it's a *"mode"*, not a *"key"* (like C, D, E).  but i sometimes swap the usage of the two terms.  i am a little sloppy with terminology.  but it sounds like a diminished "mode" (or "key") or whatever because of that flat 5th (or augmented 4th).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson - Yes, a *key* consists of a certain specified set of notes, while the *scale* is that set of notes in an ordered way - lowest>highest, and vice-versa. A key will always have a root (or *home*) note, and scales are played from that root note, generally. They're nearly interchangeable terms, but not exactly. Could be a good question to pose.

Comment: okay, one source says that the "B diminished scale" is B, C#, D, E, F, G, Ab, Bb, B.   seems to be 9 notes instead of 8.  so is the correct nomenclature is that the *"mode"* is "*diminished*"?  and if it's B, C, D, E, F, G, A, B would the scale be "B Locrian" and the mode is "Locrian"?  With minor 3rd and dim 5th, they both sound diminished.

Answer (score 10):

The simple/traditional approach is for the chords to match the scales you're improvising over. You wouldn't improvise with C Lydian in your right hand and simultaneously play a CMaj11 chord--the F in your left hand would clash with the F♯ in your right hand. Similarly, if you improvise over the V7 chord using the G altered scale, you wouldn't simultaneously play a G9 chord--the A♭ in your right hand would clash with the A♮ in your left hand.

To your question "are modes in jazz primarily a melody thing?" the answer is: modes are simply fancy names for scales. These scales can be used to define the melody *and* the harmony. The straightforward approach is for those two things (melody and harmony) to agree with each other.

One small terminology note: just because you're using a mode to solo doesn't mean you're improvisation is "modal." The adjective "modal" usually refers to a style of composition that avoids traditional harmony, etc. Simply using a mode to construct an improvisation wouldn't qualify the solo as "modal."

Comment: As an aside, if you want to break from the more traditional convention, you *could* play a left-hand chord that clashes with the right-hand improvisation.

Comment: Or you could play some melodic line way outside what your band is comping with, happens all the time. +1

Comment: @user45266, totally agree. I was trying to distinguish from those scenarios by using words like straightforward, simple, traditional, etc. but it didn't quite feel right because of how established it is to go out!

Comment: Yeah, and I think you did a good job doing it, but when I find an opportunity to be nitpicky, no force on this Earth can stop me! :)

Comment: @user45266 Haha, not nitpicky at all--a useful addition! foreyez, it's worth mentioning that there are many songs where the chords don't all fit diatonically into one key. There's a spectrum. On one end is e.g. Autumn Leaves, & on the other end is e.g. Giant Steps. As you spend more time studying jazz you'll encounter more songs with non-diatonic chords. Some of the first ones I ever encountered were **[I Love You](http://www.guitarcats.com/images/JazzStandardCharts/BEAUTIFUL%20LOVE-39.jpg)** and **[Beautiful Love](http://www.guitarcats.com/images/JazzStandardCharts/BEAUTIFUL%20LOVE-39.jpg)**

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding over-critical, your example of Dm7 - G7 - Cmaj7 using the three modes of D Dorian - G Mixolydian - C Lydian (or maybe C Ionian?) would in fact be using the same 7 notes all through the sequence. With your change of #4 in C Lydian. That idea is as simple as one would use when improvising over those three chords in any case - obvious target notes being D, G and C in turn.

Since you're talking 'scales and modes', this will be essentially melody playing. Over existing chords, usually belonging to an already written song - a standard, maybe. So the harmony/chords are already there to be played over, denying them the pleasure of being labelled 'modal' anyway.

So, I don't think there is any particular 'modality' involved here.

Also, ♭9 isn't always an avoid note - I use it regularly - it has as much credence, being a semitone away from a potential target note, as the leading note has.

Comment: When both the lower chromatic neighbor and the upper chromatic neighbor are combined you get the _enclosure_. Definitely not always an avoid tone.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, an enclosure doesn't have to us a half step above. Perhaps the most common enclosure in bebop is a half step below the target and a scale step above the target.

Answer (score 1):

You're sort using *mode* and *modal* interchangeably, but you probably shouldn't. *Modal* implies a jazz style different from your `ii V I` type playing. The essence of this question was covered in questions you asked previously. I don't really understand why you've posted again.

Yes, you are describing the "chord/scale" approach correctly. The kind of thing you find from Jamey Abersold...

[image]

...on that page he uses Ionian for the `I` chord, and the solid note heads apparently are for the chord tones. This one just shows `ii V I` in all major keys.

I think it strange how the lesson is titled with "all major keys", but then it doesn't show key signatures, but spells out the scale with accidentals. I really don't understand this attitude from jazz teaching. It seems to me on one hand they acknowledge major/minor keys are in effect, but then don't want to use key signatures. Notice also Roman numeral analysis is used in the title `ii/V7/I`, but then some people say jazz harmony is chromatic and non-functional. *I* understand it, but from a teaching perspective it seems confusing for a beginner. The chord/scale system seems like an attempt to avoid learning functional harmony.

Anyway, Abersold has special lead sheet for jazz standards that look similar to this `ii V I` lesson where the chord changes are above the staff and the basic scale is notated. For example, he has *Maiden Voyage* with changes and notated scales. The idea seems clear: the chords come from an original song and scales are selected to match the given chords...

[image]

The other option - the historical way - is to play the arpeggios for the chord changes with embellishments like diatonic passing tones or lower chromatic neighbor tones.

---

EDIT

From these comments...

> To play in a mode is more than just playing the right notes. You need to make the root of the mode feel like home and that is the difference between playing in C major or D Dorian. Same notes but D sounds like home in one and C in the other – b3ko

...and...

> @b3ko exactly, I guess my question is does the harmony/left-hand change that root or does it keep it in the original scale. I've been looking at jazz standards and they all seem diatonic (except for secondary dominants) as far as whatever scale is currently being played harmony wise. the melody however, really changes things up when improvisation is concerned. – foreyez

...I get the sense you are confusing the idea of *tonic* and chord *root.*

The wording in those comments should be *tonic of the mode* when speaking of scales and tonal centers. *Root* should only be used when talking about chords.

When you play `C: ii7 V7 I` it is diatonic, the key is `C` major, the tonic is `C`.

The root of `ii7` is `D` but it doesn't mean the *tonic* has changed to `D` Dorian. The tonality isn't switching from `C` major to `D` Dorian. The harmony is not modal. The chord root is `D` and the tonic is `C`. In such a case Dorian is just a *fiction* of the chord/scale system.

The similarity of playing a full octave scale from `D4` to `D5` in `C` major to `D` Dorian is coincidental. The real difference between the two is entirely a matter of how the harmony is handled.

At the risk of mixing styles, I think a classical example offers a good comparison. This is a famous passage, scale based, clearly diatonic, in `C` major...

[image]

https://imslp.org/images/4/48/TN-Mozart_Werke_Breitkopf_Serie_20_KV545.jpg

...conveniently the harmony is `ii7 V4/2 I`. The treble part is  a scale `F4` to `F5`, but no sensible analysis would say the passage is in `F` Lydian. All the tones for `F` Lydian are there, and there is an `F` Lydian scale, but that is coincidental and doesn't matter. The harmony is what counts and it's clearly `C` major.

We can compare that to the follow from a handout from a jazz improvisation college course...

[image]

http://www.mikesteinel.com/resources/A-Guide-To-Change-Running.pdf

...the treble part plays the *exact same* descending line. It's all the tones for `F` Lydian, but it makes no sense to identify it that way. It's in `C` major.

The chord/scale system would describe this descending line as `^3` to `^7` of `D` Dorian followed by `^3` to `^7` of `G` Mixolydian ending on `^3` or `C` Ionian. All of which is coincidental to the completely obvious point that the *whole line* is `F5` to `E4` in `C` major.

That example is a bit unrealistic, because it's just part of a lesson. We can use another example that looks more like a real improvisation...

[image]

...the line over `Dm7` certainly *looks* like it's a partial `D` Dorian scale. But the important point is the music is not in `D` Dorian. It doesn't matter that you played a nearly complete `D` Dorian scale starting on the purported `D` tonic. That `D` Dorian look-a-like scale is just a coincidence. The passage is simply in `C` major. It isn't even temporarily in `D` Dorian.

> ...I guess my question is does the harmony/left-hand change that [tonic] or does it keep it in the original scale?

No. When you play anything that is properly a `ii7` or `V7` you are not changing the tonic. Yes, it keeps to the original scale of `C` major. Playing `D4` to `D5` over a `ii7` in `C` major is just playing the `C` major scale except your aren't starting on the tonic.

The chord/scale system notion that it is a `D` Dorian scale simply because you started on `D` and ascended step-wise can just be turned around. If we *dont't* do that and play something like this...

[image]

...why should be regard it as derived from `D` Dorian? There isn't a step-wise scale, there isn't even a `D`!

Of course the reply is: it *is not* derived from `D` Dorian. It is derived from `C` major and emphasizes the chord tones of `ii7` with the `E` extending it to `ii9` or it could be regarded as an anticipated appoggiatura to the chord tone `D` of `G7`.

I think you should really look at other jazz methods and not stick doggedly to the chord/scale system. That system has it's critics and there are people who teach a functional harmony/chord tone approach.

Comment: I never asked a question asking explicitly if modes are used in melody versus harmony.

Comment: Also on one hand you're saying I'm describing it correctly, but on the other hand jdjazz is saying that both the melody and harmony use modes. so I'm still confused.

Comment: I added an image of an Abersold lesson so you can see one way it is taught.

Comment: @foreyez, there's a phrasing here, but there's also something more substantive at issue. First the phrasing issue: a mode is just a scale. The mode we use to improvise can *influence* the chord we choose. But that doesn't change the fact that the mode is a scale, and it doesn't change the fact that a chord is a chord. That said, we can choose chords that match modes. If you want, you can often think of it as though we're building a chord using 1-3-5-7 (etc.) from the selected mode.

Comment: @foreyez, on the substantive issue. To me it seems like Michael Curtis & I disagree. I don't fully understand what he's looking at when he says "you are describing the 'chord/scale' approach correctly." I tend to disagree, and I think your original statement ("that'd just be my right hand doing that modal stuff--and keep away from b9 avoid notes with whatever chord tone I’m currently on--and my left hand remains in C major") does *not* describe the "traditional" approach. The traditional approach is: if you change the mode in the right hand, then make the corresponding change in the left hand.

Comment: If you listen to old live tracks with Brad Mehldau & Joshua Redman, you can hear Josh going out during his solo, & Brad deviating from the written chords to follow along. If you're comping while a horn solos, you're generally expected to listen for chord substitutions & follow along if you hear them occurring. A saxophonist I used to play with had favorites: on a ii-V-I at the end of a tune, he would frequently add another ii-V a minor third up, which is pretty common. He also liked to replace ii-V-I's with Coltrane changes. The expectation is that I'd hear this & play the substituted chords.

Comment: But if you listen to some of the free jazz that Coltrane produced near the end of his career, you'll hear the piano playing chords that clearly clash with the saxophone. Oftentimes, no attempt is being made by the pianist to match the melody that Coltrane is creating. That wasn't really the point, and that objective didn't exist in those tracks in the same way that it does on, e.g., a more straight-ahead Stan Getz track.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, the Lydian example is the one foreyez specifically asks about. I see what he means, but a more dramatic example would be "do you play the G altered scale in your right hand and a regular G9 chord in your left hand?" That's the question he's asking: should the left hand stick to the written chords/key while the right hand is using modes to deviate. I don't think he's asking how to pair chords with scales in general, and when I read your answer, I wonder if we interpreted the question differently. Also, Maiden Voyage is a great example of the value of notating every accidental.

Comment: @foreyez, I see your question (a) describing a technique where you play "outside" of the written key in your right hand while simultaneously playing "inside" the written key with your left hand and (b) asking whether this is the typical approach. While it's not typical, I certainly don't want to suggest that the technique you describe is prohibited. It is more of a modern, edgy, or dissonant sound. But the common wisdom is for the harmony to follow the melody during instances where the melody deviates.

Comment: @jdjazz, the OP isn't asking about all those outside ideas. From the OP question and comments: "the harmony is generally diatonic chords of the scale (say ii7-V7-I7)" and " I've been looking at jazz standards and they all seem diatonic (except for secondary dominants)"

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, I disagree. "The improvisation (as an example) would be D Dorian, G Mixolydian, C Lydian. So in a piano, **that'd just be my right hand doing that modal stuff** ... and my left hand **remains in C major.**" The OP considers C Lydian to be outside of C Major, and is distinguishing the right hand (in C Lydian) from the left hand (which remains in C Major and doesn't follow the modal choice).

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, see also: "I think the **improvised melodies** are modal and sometimes **altered modal scales.* But we're **just talking about the melody** right? They **keep** the harmony [i.e., left hand] **diatonic** chords?" The OP says that the right hand (which plays melodies) uses the "altered modes" while the left hand (which plays chords) "keeps" with "diatonic chords." CMaj#11 is not diatonic to CMaj.

Comment: I read "I think... sometimes altered modal..." The OP is tentative about what is expected in the improvized melody. More importantly the OP does not include any example specifically about a conflict between scale and chord tones. _You_ are adding that complication. And using `#^4` (Lydian mode if one insists on using chord/scale terms) can be played over a plain `Cmaj7` without necessarily changing the chord to `Cmaj7#11`.

Comment: @jdjazz, can you put all those comments in response to foreyez in _your_ answer please? I read your reply to me about conflicting scales and chords. I don't think that is the main point of the OP.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit those in. I commented here too because the way you characterized my answer was different from how I was thinking about my answer, and different from how I was thinking about the question. @foreyez, can you clarify what you meant in your question?

Comment: @foreyez, can you pose that question to jdjazz on _his_ answer? (I deleted my comment about his answer) Let him explain it in his own words. I think you understand the essence of the chord/scale system. But I am also a critic of that system. You don't seem confused. That system has flaws.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis, the chord/scale system is the widest use approach to teach jazz improvisation by college professors. It's endorsed and utilized by many giants in jazz--not just Jamey Aebersold.